# ToDate function not returning as expected

Tags: oracle

I am filtering the data base on ETD_Date which is date type . And my filter is

```
AND OMB.ETD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('3/11/2019 12:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY 
  HH:MI:SS AM') AND TO_DATE('3/11/2019 11:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
```

its returning me zero rows, but when i checked my in table i do have 
 "3/11/2019  5:00:00 PM" and "3/11/2019  7:45:00 PM" .I tried to exchange AM/PM  as

```
 OMB.ETD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('3/11/2019 12:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') AND TO_DATE('3/11/2019 11:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

buy it won't work. what should be my filter so that i get expected result.

Comment: I prefer to avoid using am/pm format .. just use 24hr format .. it removes all of the vagueness :)   to_date('3/11/2019 12:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')   and  to_date('3/11/2019 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  try that and see if it works better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AM` or `PM` must appear in the date string too. As in

```
AND OMB.ETD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('3/11/2019 12:00:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
                     AND TO_DATE('3/11/2019 11:59:59 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
```

The advice above to get used to using a 24 hour clock is also something you should do. So try:

```
AND OMB.ETD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('3/11/2019 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                     AND TO_DATE('3/11/2019 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Or you can just ignore the time for the most part:

```
AND OMB.ETD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('3/11/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
                     AND TO_DATE('3/12/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

The latter version works because the time portion of a `DATE` defaults to `00:00:00` if it isn't specified, and subtracting one second from midnight gives you `23:59:59`.

Best of luck.